# C# - doesn't send any error message but doesn't work properly

Tags: c#, regex, syntax, methods

What am I doing wrong? I don't receive any error message but it doesn't work properly -

the part of code:

```
    int n = Convert.ToInt32(args.Content);
    if (n >= 10000)
        n = (int) (n - (n * 0.85));
    return n.ToString();
```

works only when I comment the previous part of code:

```
    Match match = Regex.Match(args.Content, "ca.*?2013", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);  
    if (match.Success)
        args.Content = match.Groups[1].Value + "Aktl.";
    return args.Content;
```

Bellow is the full script:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using VisualWebRipper.Internal.SimpleHtmlParser;
using VisualWebRipper;
public class Script
{
    //See help for a definition of WrContentTransformationArguments.
    public static string TransformContent(WrContentTransformationArguments args)
    {
        try
        {
            //Place your transformation code here.
            //This example just returns the input data

            Match match = Regex.Match(args.Content, "ca.*?2013", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);  
            if (match.Success)
                args.Content = match.Groups[1].Value + "Aktl.";
            return args.Content;
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(args.Content);
            if (n >= 10000)
                n = (int) (n - (n * 0.85));
            return n.ToString();
        }
        catch(Exception exp)
        {
            //Place error handling here
            args.WriteDebug("Custom script error: " + exp.Message);
            return "Custom script error";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot return twice from a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need:

```
        if (match.Success)
        {
            args.Content = match.Groups[1].Value + "Aktl.";
            return args.Content;
        }
```

In:

```
        if (match.Success)
            args.Content = match.Groups[1].Value + "Aktl.";
        return args.Content;
```

`return` statement is always executed and makes rest of the code unreachable. Conditional expression - `if(...)` - without brackets only includes next statement following the `if` check, that's way `return` is always executed.

Comment: Great, you're welcome. I'm glad it helped, if you consider this answer most helpful you can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
return args.Content;
```

You are returning on this line from the function, the control won't go below that.